# Gridview Issue - Updates the wrong value on Edit/Update

Tags: gridview

I am working on an app that I inherited and trying to find out what is going on. There is a gridview that uses ObjectDataSource. The ObjectDataSource looks at a dataset to get holiday data (Holiday Name and Date) and the gridview displays this. Users should be able to click on Edit and edit a date associated to the Holiday. *Note that the Holiday is the primary Key in the database table and in the dataset.* For some annoying reason, when I click edit on any row, I can edit and Update a date and it will always only update the first row in the table with that date which is not associated with the holiday the user is trying to update. I have copied my Update code below. What is going wrong here?

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethod
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
public bool UpdateHolidays(string Original_Holiday, DateTime Original_Date)
{
    GetHolidayData.HolidaysDataTable holidays = Adapter.GetData();
    if (holidays.Count == 0)
        // no matching record found, return false
       return false;
    GetHolidayData.HolidaysRow holiday = holidays[0];

    if (Original_Date == null) holiday.SetDateNull();
    else holiday.Date = Original_Date.Date;

    int rowsAffected = Adapter.Update(holiday);
    return rowsAffected == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to trash this thing. Went with an Entity Model, Model Classes, and List View instead and rebuild the project infrastructure. Works great! I have no idea what the prior developer was trying to accomplish with the grid view but from what I have researched, they are very tricky to get working right.